# python original dictionary being modified after each iteration

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, copy

I have tried to implement Karger's algorithm to compute min cut of a graph by python, and tested my code with a small input graph. Basically I make a copy of the original input graph for every iteration, but after running the code for one iteration the original input graph is somehow modified. Where does my code go wrong?

```
import random

def random_contraction(graph):
    u = random.choice(graph.keys())
    v = random.choice(graph[u])
        for node in graph[v]:
        for vertex in graph[node]:
            if vertex == v:
                graph[node].remove(vertex)
                graph[node].append(u)
    graph[u] = graph[u] + graph[v]
    graph[u] = [node for node in graph[u] if (node != u and node != v)]
    graph.pop(v, None)

def min_cut(graph):
    while len(graph) > 2:
        random_contraction(graph)
    node = random.choice(graph.keys())
    return len(graph[node])

graph_input = {0:[1,3,4,5], 1:[0,2,4],2:[1,3,5],3:[0,2],4:[0,1],5:[0,2]}
list_min_cut = []
for dummy_idx in range(100):
    print "original", graph_input 
    #check the original input graph at the beginning of iteration
    graph = dict(graph_input)
    #make a copy of original input graph
    list_min_cut.append(min_cut(graph))
print min(list_min_cut)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy using `dict()` it will only create a *shallow* copy. This means the copying is not done recursively, so the new `dict` will contain references to the original lists, rather than copies of them.

To perform a *deep* copy, you can use [deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
from copy import deepcopy
...

for dummy_idx in range(100):
    print "original", graph_input 
    graph = deepcopy(graph_input)
```